# Angular JS disabled button when input text empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I start in angular JS and I want to disable (attribute "ng-disabled") a button while my input text "login" and "password" are empty. The problem is that, by default the text of input-text "login" is "LOGIN" and the text of input-text "password" is "PASSWORD", so my inputs are never empty...

Help,

Thanks

Comment: Set them as `null`/`""` and use the html [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute

Comment: Can you explain that you say by 'Set them as null/""' please

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a **placeholder** instead of populating it with something

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pass = ""; // empty, instead of "PASSWORD"
  $scope.foo = () => {
    console.log($scope.pass);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input placeholder="PASSWORD" ng-model="pass">
  <button ng-click="foo()" ng-disabled="!pass">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

Here is another example that suits your description, where you can populate it with some text, but still have the button disabled. It uses `ng-focus` to reset the input field if it is selected, and it has `$dirty` checking, to only allow to press the button when the input has been altered/changed.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pass = "PASSWORD";
  $scope.foo = () => {
    console.log($scope.pass);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <input ng-focus="pass=''" name="pass" ng-model="pass">
    <button ng-click="foo()" ng-disabled="!form.pass.$dirty || !pass">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect

Comment: @Benj I made another example that could also work (**if you need to** populate the variable, but still disable the button, until it's changed), but this solution is not recommended.